# Операции над элементами массива

Tags: c++

1. Как сравнить 2 рядом стоящих элемента и в случае их неравенства выйти из цикла?
2. Как определить  номер строки двумерного массива, сумма элементов которой максимальна? Каким образом это лучше сделать?

-

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <locale.h>

#define HB 5

void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian"); // вывод на русском языке
    int a[HB];          // массив
    int k;          // индекс
    int ok;         // 1 - последовательность неубывающая

    printf("Проверка, упорядочен ли массивn");
    printf("по возрастаниюn");
    printf("Введите массив (%i целых чисел ", HB);
    printf("в одной строке) и нажмите <Enter>n");
    for (k = 0; k < HB; k++)
    scanf("%i", &a[k]);

    k = 0;
    ok = 1;
    do {
    if (a[k] > a[k + 1])
        ok = 0;
    k++;
    } while (k < HB - 1 && ok);

    printf("Элементы массива ");
    if (!ok)
    printf("не ");
    printf("упорядочены по возрастаниюn");

    printf("nДля завершения работы нажмите <Enter>");

    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сравнение двух соседних:

```
for (k = 0; k < HB - 1; k++)
{
    if (a[k] != a[k + 1])
       break;   
}
```

Поиск строки с максимальной суммой элементов:

```
maxRowIndex = -1;
maxSum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   sum = 0;
   for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
   {
      sum += mas[i][j];
   }
   if (maxSum < sum || maxRowIndex == -1)
   {
      maxSum = sum;
      maxRowIndex = i;
   }
}
```

Где n - количество строк, m - количество столбцов, maxSum максимальная сумма элементов строки на текущий момент, sum - сумма элементов текщей строки, maxRowIndex - индекс строки с максимальной суммой элементов.

Comment: Это вы про что?

Comment: Прошу прощения, случайно во время набора текста нажал "Ответить на вопрос"

Comment: Я понял) с кем не бывает) спасибо огромное)

Comment: а как проверить, представляют ли элементы введенного с клавиатуры массива убывающую  последовательность?

Comment: Знак в строчке if (a[k] < a[k+1]) заменить на >